# Node.js/WebRTC: webrtc-adapter does not handle mediaDevice.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

Currently I have the following in my WebRTC application:

```
require('webrtc-adapter');
module.exports.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia;
```

navigator.getUserMedia gives a deprecation warning in my console.

Using now `module.exports.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia;` results to the following error:

> TypeError: 'getUserMedia' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface MediaDevices.

Any idea why webrt-adapter does not takes care of it at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write my own wrapper for `getUserMedia`:

```
module.exports.getUserMedia = function(constraints, success, error){
    if(_.isObject(navigator.mediaDevices) && _.isFunction(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream)=>{
            success(stream);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            error(err);
        })
    } else if(_.isFunction(navigator.getUserMedia)){
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, success, error);
    } else {
        error(new Error('Failed to request media permissions!'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this optimized code. Also, using webkits to support getusermedia on all browsers.

```js
module.exports.getUserMedia = async function(constraints, success, error){
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        success(stream);
    } catch(err) {
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, success, error);
        } else {
            error(new Error('Failed to request media permissions!'));
        }
    }
}
```